# Как сделать поиск в бд на кириллице? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть код:

```
result = Items.objects.filter(name__contains='White Elitebook')
```

Он находит в магазине товар. Однако если ему передать слово на кириллице, то ничего не выдает. Как сделать поиск в бд на кириллице?

Comment: БД какая? PostgreSQL? Локаль сортировки настраивали?

Comment: @VladislavMoshikov, sqlite. От бд тоже зависит? Наверное не настраивал. Даже не знаю, что это такое)

Comment: По умолчанию SQLite использует кодировку UTF-8, однако полнотекстовый поиск доступен только по кодировке ASCII. У меня нет возможности сейчас протестировать гипотезу, но я бы порекомендовал попробовать воспользоваться encode 
`encode_name = 'White Elitebook'.encode('utf-8')` `result = Items.objects.filter(name__contains=encode_name)` @Denzel